# Get user account detail using PayUMoney

Tags: android, integration, payumoney

I want to integrate PayUMoney, it's working fine but I want to show the detail of user account, right now I'm getting only payment id instead of I want the all details.
Is it possible to get all details of user transaction?
Thanks help will be appreciate.

Comment: Please guys help to solve it!